# Native Vector<Double> in LabView as an Argument/Return

Tags: c++, vector, labview

I am making a wrapper for C++ DLLs. In the function I need to return a `vector<double>`. I studied the documents and read that we can only return `int` and `string`. For returning any other variables we need to pass it as an argument. But the available variable types are `Numeric`, `String`, `Array`. So how can I get `vector<double>` from the native function in LabView.

Comment: I'll bet that you need to return an array of doubles. `vector<>` is an implementation detail.

Comment: vector<> is not an implementation detail depending a) upon which parts of the code (C or G) are going to be reading/manipulating the set of doubles and b) how much performance hit you can tolerate copying to/from different data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ vector is stored as an array, if v is `vector <double>` first element address is `&v[0]`. In LabVIEW CLFN node allows you to pass an array by pointer or by handle. So, you have 3 solutions:

1. Pass a pre-allocated array into your DLL (by pointer), fill it in, it will be available after the CLFN finishes execution.
2. Pass an array to the CLFN by handle, resize it accordingly by LabVIEW memory manager, and the contents of the array will be available after the CLFN finishes execution.
3. If the array is really big (100s of MB), and you really have to use std:vector in your C++ code I would suggest to define your own allocator based on LabVIEW memory manager to avoid copying.

Comment: One more possible option for a special case: Does LabVIEW need to operate on that vector? If your DLL is going to return the vector and then it will be operated on only by being passed back into your DLL or some other DLL, you can pass it as a pointer.

Comment: @srm possible, if memory management can not be controlled. However, it is best when memory is managed by the LabVIEW memory manager, so all allocations/deallocations are done either within LabVIEW or by the memory manager functions. If so, I would prefer to pass around a handle, not a pointer.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I accepted your answer. I did little differently but you were the most closest. I need one more help. I am plotting a graph in LabVIEW using `waveform graph` and need to fill the space under the graph with color programmatically. Any idea. I can do it by using property box but i want to do it in runtime.

Comment: @SaadSaadi. It looks to me you are talking about changing the plot type. Can you elaborate, please, maybe with a point-by-point instruction of how you do it manually, or with a picture.